# Blinking Random Number Generator ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3

I need a random number generator on AS3 that blinks on a screen one random number per second (1-9). The random number is fine but I'm having a problem with the blinking part. It just stays permanent on the screen instead of blinking the number. 
The dynamic textbox is called myNumbers. I've tried using myNumbers.visible = !myNumbers.visible on the event handler, but it didn't work.

My code:

```
var mytimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,10); 
mytimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
mytimer.start();

function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void{
        var numbers:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 1 + 1) + 1);
        myNumbers.text = numbers+"";
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same `Timer` to generate a number (every second) and blinks your text field (every 0.5 second).

Take this code :

```
var number:int = 0;

var timer:Timer = new Timer(500); 
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
    timer.start();

function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void{        
    if(timer.currentCount % 2 == 0){
        text_field.alpha = 0.2;             // you can use text_filed.visible = false;
    } else {
        text_field.alpha = 1;               // you can use text_filed.visible = true;
        number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;      
        text_field.text = String(number);   // you can also write it : number.toString();   
    }

}
```

Which will give you something like this :

[image]

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the `myNumbers` before start a timer:

```
myNumbers.visible = false;
```

In the `timerHandler` add:

```
myNumbers.visible = true;
setTimeout(hideText, 500);
```

Add `hideText` function:

```
function hideText()
{
    myNumbers.visible = false;
}
```